# If $G$ is an abelian group, $p$ a prime number, then the set $H_p$ of all elements whose order is a power of $p$ is a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm currently self learning some Abstract Algebra, starting with Group theory.

One of the books I'm using is "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Charles C. Pinter, from where I picked this exercise.

I found some similar questions here where people where struggling to prove closure by multiplication because it's not specified that $p$ is prime. I just made that assumption and moved forward. However I'm struggling to prove closure by inverses. As far as I know, I didn't find this part of the question here. Supposing it is indeed a subgroup, the rest of exercise is already done, I just need this little part in the middle.

What I tried so far is the following: Let the order of $x$ be $p^k$. Then $x^{p^k}=e$. This implies $x^{p^k-1}x = e$ so that $x^{-1} = x^{p^k-1}$.

But is $x^{p^k-1}$ an element of $H_p$?

I also know this exercise is kind of a prelude to $p$-groups and stuff, but I haven't studied those yet.

Comment: Not following.  The problem statement clearly specifies that $p$ is prime.  Further, the order of the inverse is always the same as the order of the element.

Comment: In the book, it wasn't specified that $p$ is prime, which led to people asking the question about closure by multiplication.

Comment: As for the order of element, and order of inverse...I just can't believe I forgot it!

Comment: If $p$ is not a prime, there seems to be a problem.  Say $p=6$ and let $g$ be an element of order $6$.  Then $g^2$ has order $3$ so $g\in H_6$ but $g^2\not \in H_6$.

Comment: Indeed. Which is why I just assumed the author forgot to specify it and assumed that $p$ is in fact prime.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the one-step subgroup test.

Fix a prime $p$.

Since $|e|=p^0$, we have $e\in H_p$. Hence $H_p\neq\varnothing$.

By definition, we have

$$H_p:=\{g\in G\mid \exists k\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}, |g|=p^k\}\subseteq G.$$

Let $x,y\in H_p$. Then there exist $m,n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ with $|x|=p^m$ and $|y|=p^n$. Now since $G$ is abelian $|xy^{-1}|$ divides

$$\begin{align}
{\rm lcm}(|x|,|y^{-1}|)&={\rm lcm}(p^m,|y|)&(|g^{-1}|=|g|\forall g\in G)\\
&={\rm lcm}(p^m,p^n)&\\
&=\max\{p^m, p^n\},&
\end{align}$$

which is either $p^m$ or $p^n$, and so implies $xy^{-1}\in H_p$.

Therefore $H_p\le G$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ commute then $|ab|=lcm(|a|,|b|)$, which is not necessarily the same as $|a|\cdot |b|$. It will still be a power of $p$ though, so it is easily fixed.

Comment: Thank you, @JaapScherphuis. I have corrected it now.

Comment: In fact, we only know $|ab|$ *divides* ${\rm lcm}(|a|,|b|)$, @JaapScherphuis.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For example the permutations (1234) and (1432)(56) both have order 4, but their product has order 2, or more simply you can have $b=a^{-1}$. Sorry!